# What is the correct word for “the inside of humans soul”?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I'm trying to make up a sentence that describes one of the goals of réalisme. I need to explain, that réalisme is trying to capture and describe the story that is happening inside the characters, rather than the actual events. So simply:

> Naturalism is trying to capture the inside of human soul

If I'm wrong with this statement, please correct me. I'm not a literature student.
This is what I'd say:

> *Le naturalisme essaie d'expliquer les entrailles des personnages*.

Comment: Naturalisme ou réalisme ? Il faut choisir. Quoique...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sticking to your description “réalisme is trying to capture and describe the story that is happening inside the characters, rather than the actual events”, I would suggest the following:

> Le Réalisme s'attache à restituer la psyché des personnages.

Now, if you really think of this as “capturing the inside of human soul”, you might consider something less prosaic. Maybe the following:

> Le Réalisme entend reproduire les dimensions intérieures de l'être.

Answer (score 12):

As is, it doesn't mean what you think, since *les entrailles* means literally *the guts*. If you want a translation, I have several propositions:

- *try* could be rendered as *essaie*, *tente* or *vise à*
- *capture* as *appréhender*, *restituer*, *retranscrire* or simply *capturer*
- *the inside* as *les profondeurs* or *les tréfonds*
- *the human soul* as *l'esprit humain*, *l'âme humaine*

I would go for

> *Le naturalisme vise à appréhender les profondeurs de l'âme humaine.*

Comment: Thank you for all the propositions, they surely will be useful in the future.

Answer (score -2):

« Spleen » ça se peut ?

> Le beau est toujours bizarre.
>    — Baudelaire

Sinon, je dirais

> Le naturalisme tente d'expliquer l'âme de l'être humaine.

Comment: Suggestion discutable, moi en tout cas j'aimerais bien un peu plus d'explications. Tout de même, bienvenue :)